# What language is this tattoo? what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

[image]

What does this tattoo mean? what language is this guys?

Comment: 安琪儿. Maybe equivalent to "angel", which has a similar pronunciation.

Comment: @xbh It could also be a foreign name translation.

Answer (score 3):

安琪儿 which doesn't mean anything except being a name. You can treat it as "Angel" since the pronunciation of 安琪儿 (ān qí ér / ān qí r) is similar to the English word "Angel"